# How difficult would it be for medieval people to deal with this acid-breathing dragon?

Tags: science-based, dragons

Dragons here are six-limbed creatures, roughly the size of a large horse (they tend to be larger than an average draft horse, but much lighter). One of their unique natural weapons is a combination of nitric and hydrochloric acid, aka: [aqua regia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aqua_regia). A dragon can store three liters of the stuff at most.

They have three ways of expelling this acid onto their enemies:

- *Drool/Vomit*: This mode allows the dragon to dissolve gold and even platinum by, depending on how much of the stuff is needed, salivating or vomiting on it. The dragon can't use this when someone's nearby due to the risk of that someone seeing the dragon's not-so-flattering side (i.e: drooling like an idiot).
- *Spray*: THE combat mode. It's able to cover a wide area, requires little aiming on the dragons part, and due to its enormous surface area, it starts acting almost instantly. The downside to it is that aqua regia can't dissolve gold in this form.
- *Spit*: an intermediate between the two, it has a good range and requires aiming. it's more wasteful than spraying, but doesn't loose the ability to dissolve gold, in exchange.

The dragon protects himself from the acid with a specialized mucosa, that functions similarly to gastric mucosa, stalling and partially neutralizing the acid with a layer of mucus. The dragon can apply the mucus on any part of his body by licking it (usually done to wounds). Regardless, dragons can't abuse their breath weapons carelessly.

In terms of physical capabilities, these are the most important aspects of a dragon:

- *Semi-powered flight*: The dragon is capable of powered flight for a short period of time, after that, he has to glide and ride thermals, if he wants to gain more altitude. Gliding ratio is 15:1, so pretty decent. Unfortunately, an attack, that manages to cut into any of the pectoral or wing muscles (it doesn't have to be deep), is able to render the dragon flightless for quite some time. Blood loss, painful injuries and fatigue also prevents the dragon from being able to take off on his own power.
- *Bones*: Dragon bones are notoriously strong, and similar to limpet teeth on the molecular level. The heart, air sacs, and parts of the digestive system, as well as the organs, that contain the acids, are located within the ribcage, which is nigh-impossible to damage even with a halberd, plus there's the keel bone.
- *Skin*: Dragons are covered with flexible scales. These scales provide protection against the dragon's acid as well as cutting and thrusting weapons.
- *Jaws*: The dragon's jaw strength is roughly same as that of a Nile crocodile. Thanks to their long necks, they also have a decent reach with it. Good for eating water melons.
- *Perception*: Dragons have good senses in general, their eyesight is on pair with a golden eagle's and they are also able to sniff out poison.
- *Intelligence*: The dragon is as intelligent as a human, but as mature as a human child.

**Potential weakpoint**: The dragon's underbelly is only covered with scales, and doesn't have the thickest layer of muscle to protect it. It's very unlikely one would be able to eviscerate the dragon, but sufficient damage to that area can still be life threatening, and will definitely put the dragon into a vulnerable position until his wounds are healed.

**Behavior**: The dragon changes positions frequently, but usually cycles between two forests and one mountain region.

Any would-be slayer will have to make the first move and locate the dragon, as the creature can and will run when he smells a trap. The dragon's activity is limited to stealing fruits, vegetables and other common food items, not because he's dependent on them, but because they taste good. He also patrols the forest and chases away hunting parties that try to enter. When the threat seems serious enough, the dragon will use his breath weapon.

**Given this information, how dangerous/difficult would hunting this dragon down be for a smaller team of knights (5-10 members), using only high-to-late medieval tech?**

Comment: I'd think a ballista would work great... a siege-grade crossbow.  Worked on Smaug, right?

Comment: By your description, a belly shot with a hand-cranked crossbow would probably do the trick.

Comment: Questions such as this "How difficult/dangerous...." tend to lead to opinion based answers by default. It does come across that you wish us to write the details of the story for you rather than answer a focused world-building question with a clear best answer. VTC story-based.

Answer (score 3):

**Very difficult, unless the knights are well prepared.**

What's most dangerous about the acid dragon is its acid. Not only can it be sprayed over a wide area but it also passes through gaps in the knights armor melting them alive while they are unable to remove their heavy armor. On top of that the dragons scales restricts the selection of weapons that can inflict real damage. Lastly the dragons mobility makes it hard to catch, which would be too difficult for armored knights.

In other words a group of knights using conventional medieval weapons would get utterly obliterated by this dragon.

**Here's a four step plan to slay an acid dragon:**

**1.** **Use shields not armor.** Heavy armor makes one very slow and clumsy, not to mention it does not protect perfectly against the acid of the dragon, which would just slip through the gaps in the armor. A shield on the other hand would work just like and umbrella protecting the wielder as long as it has enough surface area. This way if the shields melt they can be replaced.

**2.** **Use bludgeoning weapons.** The obvious response to an armored enemy is to use blunt weapons to damage them from the inside. The priority should be to target the wings or legs of the dragon first, in order to prevent it from escaping. After that striking the head or neck might be enough to finish it off. If the dragon is too tough then its better to strike at the joints and hope to dislocate its limbs and strike in the eye.

**3.** **Use a net.** In all of history hunters that have faced prey faster than themselves have used this method. If the dragon can't fly or run away it the rest will be easy. Using a net made of chains might be better than using rope as it would melt too quickly allowing the dragon a chance to escape. If the net can be fired that would be even better for taking the dragon by surprise.

**4.** **Use some sort of bait.** Be it gold, meat or a sacrificial virgin anything goes so long as it baits the dragon into attacking so the knights can take it by surprise. If a dragon were to see armed knights it could just choose to retreat instead. Using baiting tactics would make the dragon come to the knights instead of having to chase it.

Comment: But the dragon runs when he smells a trap. A sacrificial lamb sauce sounds like a trap, and even though he hates leaving delicacies behind, it's pointless if it just spills out at the other end because one of the knights gutted you.

Comment: Any animal no matter how smart can be trapped, tricked or taken by surprise. Even if your dragon has human level intelligence it doesn't mean it is immune against a surprise attack.

Comment: He isn't but the bait has to be better. Maybe a DISTRACTION CARNIFEX, but that requires some serious teamwork.

Comment: Well you're definitely difficult to please, I'll give you that. Traps are optional due to how situational they are. But a dragon can't keep running away forever, there will always be a moment of weakness. If a dragon has been chased for a week and hasn't gotten a proper meal, would it attack then? If it does it gets trapped and if it doesn't it starves to death. Or in battle it can't keep focused on the movements of every knight around it, there will inevitably be a moment where its guard is down.

Comment: That's fair. So they're fighting the dragon in a battle of attrition?

Comment: And now I just imagined a scene where the dragon is hiding inside a cave and just finished dressing a cut on his left foreleg. He curls up and falls asleep. He wakes up to the tip of a sword poking his head, and realizes the knights have already surrounded him.

Answer (score 3):

Only 3L of aqua regia is not that much. In addition, acid doesn't melt through armor like in the movies. There are videos on youtube of elemental metals being dissolved in aqua regia, but even then, steel is harder to dissolve, and you would have to submerge the armor in the acid for a long time to even begin to eat away at it.

Knights will just wipe the acid off of their armor, and the acid will have barely cleaned the dirt off of the surface. Wearing the equivalent of a lab coat under a suit of armor would protect you from any small amount of acid coming through the gaps in the armor.

A team of knights versus a dragon like this poses great danger to the dragon and little danger to the armored knights. The dragon, being smart, would run/fly away. The tricky part would be trapping the dragon(s) so that they can be easily slaughtered.

If you want the acid to be more dangerous, then you probably want the acid to mix with something, creating a gas which is toxic to humans, but to which the dragons are immune due to their unique biology. Like how acid + bleach yields chlorine gas as a product.

Just some thoughts! Love dragons and your set up sounds really cool.

Comment: knights will also likely start lacquering or painting their armor as that will greatly reduce the effectiveness of the acid.

Comment: I'm not sure, but the nitric acid component of the breath weapon does produce nitrogen oxide, which has a 3 for blue on the hazard diamond.

Comment: Yeah that sounds cool. Ideally you want a 4 for a super deadly gas >:), but anything you come up with along those lines of thinking is going to have a reasonably harmful effect. looks like nitrogen monoxide is oxidized to form NO2 (part of car exhaust) when exposed to oxygen in the air. I think the type of acid matters less though, you can use any acid... the poisonous part seems to usually come from the decomposition of the salt. So I guess try to find a reasonably inert organic molecule with a chlorine atom in it which will react with an acid to make Cl gas.

Answer (score 2):

"*The dragon's activity is limited to stealing fruits, vegetables and other common food items, not because he's dependent on them, but because they taste good.*"

So you create a dragon's table place where you leave lots of the goodies he likes and keep it in constant supply.  He goes there and leaves the rest of the territory alone.  As long as the items there are easy to get to you make any other sources hard to find and get.

Answer (score 1):

**Use tanks.**

Hire your local siege engineer to build you some sheds with wheels. Chop down a few trees, strip off the foliage and staple it to all sides of the shed. Use enough foliage to double the size of the sheds. Now there is a thick cushion of material between your knights and the acid spray.

Use much more foliage than the dragon can possibly make in one day. To see how effective this is, build a campfire and throw a load of green vegetation on top and watch how long it takes to burn up.

Now you have some mobile bushes with wheels. Gather some dung from a different dragon and slather it all over the shed so it smells like a rival dragon. Find a flat part of the dragon's territory and tie up a cow as bait. When the dragon arrives it notices a very strange looking dragon has invaded its territory. It stomps and growls and sprays all its acid$^1$ at the invader. Then, as the invader slowly wheels towards the dragon, it tries to wrestle.

**Go go go!**

Suddenly twelve lads$^2$ (also dressed as hedgerows) leap out of the shed. As the dragon wrestles the (now empty shed) all the lads dogpile the dragon.

[image]

Once the dragon is flat on its belly and there are loads of heavy people on top, you are ready to stab it through the back of the head using what is essentially an estoc.

[image]

See long inflexible piece of metal with pointed tip. For extra thrusting power install a few extra crossguards along the weapon so several lads can stab it at once.

---

1. Since dragon's are resistant to each other's acid this is a form of harmless posturing behaviour meant to scare off rivals. In fact the dragons tend not to focus fire on each other, but spray their acid in a wide scary intimidating arc while making as much noise as possible. They also do this for mating behaviour.
2. Just take the number of lads needed to capture a large nile crocodile and multiply it by two or so.

Comment: The dragon is as intelligent as a human. If he saw one of those things, and that the acid didn't work on it, he'd retreat ASAP

Comment: @Mephistopheles: Oh that's much harder. . . .

Comment: @Mephistopheles: How come the dragon's so smart? Lizards are stupid stupid.

Comment: 1. Dragons are not lizards 2. Because I wanted it that way, WRYYYYY! 3. Depends on the species and I saw people who were much dumber than your average lizard.

Comment: Though I  might be a bit biased on point 3. I mean, I just watched a video of a male water monitor running away from a female water monitor, half his size. It's hard not to think they have a lot more going on upstairs.

Comment: @Mephistopheles: Okay for smart dragons I suggest a slow and insidious trap where you trick them into a tedious day-job and a mortgage.

Answer (score 1):

It would be difficult, but definitely possible for a dedicated team to kill the Dragon, and here’s how.

**Trickery**

Since the dragon has human intelligence but poor impulse control (the maturity of a child aspect) then it can definitely be tricked. Although you say it will run off it can smell a trap, the nature of humans and children in particular is that we can be conned if you know how to do it.

Things like covertly poisoning a food supply that the knights guard but then immediately retreat from after the dragon shows up could very well work, as the dragon would presume that it was something of value to them, and wouldn’t presume poison if any effort was made to guard it. Use its intelligence against itself.

**Acid Protection**

Why wear armor made for deflecting swords and arrows when your foe spits acid? Have multiple layers of clothing that can quickly be pulled or stripped off at tear off points all over the body so that acid doesn’t have time to eat to the skin, and It’s better to be light and quick against something you can’t block. Strong mixtures based on sodium bicarbonate could be kept in flasks all over and smashed to neutralize the acid.

**Proper Weapons**

Forget swords, if your foe is flying you need range. The dragon slayers will use longbows with bodkins, arbalests, slings, and atlatls. The bodkins and atlatl darts are powerful piercing projectiles that have a track record of being very effective at range against armored foes, and will be concentrated against the dragon’s belly and wings. The sling bullets provide blunt trauma that will hurt the dragon even when striking its armored and muscled hide.

**Pick the Battlefield**

The dragon ought to be lured via bait or harassment into a pre selected part of the forest, in which it will have to deal with traps and enemies who are hiding in the trees in order to give a surprise hit to a creature that isn’t going to be looking up for its enemies.